# Why is the Google not using PWA feature for their product like google.com, youtube.com

Tags: youtube, progressive-web-apps, google-product-search

Google is recommending PWA feature for fast and reliable website, but google itself is not using PWA features for their product as you can see **google.com** or **youtube.com**. Why?

Comment: They actually [already use PWA features](https://web.dev/google-search-sw).

Answer (score 1):

I do not think storing video streams on a user's device might be a good idea, especially considering the size of the videos.
For both Google.com and youtube I do not see a PWA would be the right choice.

I wrote an [article](https://dev.to/paco_ita/a-gentle-introduction-to-progressive-web-apps-step-1-24da) - first of a series about PWAs - describing the characteristics and main purposes of Progressive Web Apps. Maybe it might give you some further insights about this technology.

**UPDATE**

It seems that youTube after all is getting into PWA after all, as [stated here](https://www.thurrott.com/music-videos/youtube-music/220832/youtube-music-is-going-pwa).

Comment: PWA is not all about Storing data, it's also giving you other feature like push notification, offline support, installable. These feature can be used by youtube but still they haven't implemented yet. Are they still supporting APP over PWA. I had watched google conference video, where they have mentioned that they are going to provide all the feature of APP in PWA.